# How to calculate cache miss rate

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm trying to answer computer architecture **past paper question (NOT a Homework)**.
My question is how to calculate the miss rate.(complete question ask to calculate the average memory access time) The complete question is,

> For a given application, 30% of the instructions require memory access. Miss rate is 3%. An instruction can be executed in 1 clock cycle. L1 cache access time is approximately 3 clock cycles while L1 miss penalty is 72 clock cycles. Calculate the average memory access time.

**Needed equations,**

- Average memory access time = Hit time + Miss rate x Miss penalty
- Miss rate = no. of misses / total no. of accesses (This was found from stackoverflow)

As I mentioned above I found how to calculate miss rate from stackoverflow ( I checked that question but it does not answer my question) but the problem is I cannot imagine how to find Miss rate from given values in the question.

**What I have done up to now**

```
 Average memory access time = 30% * (1 + 3% * 72) + 100% * (1 + M*72)
```

M - miss rate

what I need to find is M. (If I am correct up to now if not please tell me what I've messed up)

Comment: The exercise appears to be assuming that the instruction fetch miss rate and data access miss rate are the same (3% would be the aggregate miss rate *and* the miss rate of each component). However, it is also conceivable that it is assuming a perfect instruction cache (this assumption can be useful in limit studies). When making assumptions because a question appears to have insufficient information, declaring one's assumptions is important (but commonly not possible for multiple choice).

Comment: What about the "3 clock cycles" ? Then for what it stands for?

Comment: If one assumes aggregate miss rate, one could assume 3 cycle latency for any L1 access (whether separate I and D caches or a unified L1). If one assumes perfect Icache, one would probably only consider data memory access time. (Sadly, poorly expressed exercises are all too common. The phrasing seems to assume only data accesses are memory accesses ["require memory access"], but one could as easily assume that "besides the instruction fetch" is implicit.)

Comment: Is the answer 2.221 clock cycles per instruction?